# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

```
$epay_params['merchantnumber'] = *******;
    $epay_params['transactionid'] = $id;
    $epay_params['amount'] = 0;
    $epay_params['pbsResponse'] = -1;
    $epay_params['epayresponse'] = -1;

    $client = new SoapClient('https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment.asmx?WSDL');

    $result = $client->credit($epay_params);
    print_r($result)
```

it's give error like

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR:
>   Encoding: object has no 'pbsresponse' property ...

when call this function it's give. help me in this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got solution of my question. i just replace 'r' with 'R'.

```
updated code
$epay_params['merchantnumber'] = *******;
$epay_params['transactionid'] = $id;
$epay_params['amount'] = 0;
$epay_params['pbsresponse'] = -1;
$epay_params['epayresponse'] = -1;

$client = new SoapClient('https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment.asmx?WSDL');

$result = $client->credit($epay_params);
print_r($result)
```